# JMeter SOAP request with attachement

Tags: file, soap, jmeter, attachment

I'm using JMeter to test a web-service (SOAP), the method I'm testing takes an argument of type file. In SOAP UI this can be done by uploading an attachment and providing it an ID.

In the soap request then something like this would be placed:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"     xmlns:ws="http://zk.payment.dkv.be/ws">
  <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
      <ws:wsMethod>
          <file>cid:attachementID</file>
      </ws:wsMethod>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I'm using Jmeter 2.9 and it seems this is not possible, any one has a workaround?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest creating custom Soap Sampler that has attachments handling enabled.
The solution (sources, built JAR in target folder) is under github:
https://github.com/spinning10/JMeterSoapSampler

Please also checkout our testing blog:
http://driven-by-tests.blogspot.be/

The built jar (latest, compiled under Java 1.7) is under: https://github.com/spinning10/JMeterSoapSampler/blob/master/target/CustomSoapSampler-1.3.jar

You can also find this sampler available to download if you install "Plugin Manager" from the site: http://jmeter-plugins.org/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11048142)

Comment: I included the links you expected. May you un-downvote me?

Comment: The jar provided in the github is compiled against java 8, so be sure to run JMeter with java 8. Tested with JMeter 2.9 and soap 1.1 message.

Answer (score 1):

So at this time of writing JMeter does not have the solution to do the above. Well not by sending an attachment directly, but there is a workaround!

Because at the very end it's all about whats between the tag:

```
<file>"what is here??"</file>
```

It's all about what between the above tag, thats the only thing which matters for your service. Then the workaround:

```
<file><![CDATA[${yourContentJMeterVariableName}]]></file>
```

"yourContentJMeterVariableName" is basically a Jmeter variable, which has to be filled in by let's say a Beanshell preprocessor (ignoring all the imports) like so:

```
try {
   String path = "pathToYourContentFileOrAttachement";
   String content = new Scanner(new File(path)).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
   byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(content.getBytes());
   vars.put("yourContentJMeterVariableName", new String(encoded));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     log.error(e);
}
```

Above I've ignored the imports for the sake of this post, but  the less obvious ones would be:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
```

They should already be included in the lib of jmeter. So that's it!

Comment: Where do the imports go?

Answer (score 1):

I have used similar solution what Fico mentioned, try below code.

```
File file = new File("C:\\103861\\A1940599.zip");
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
long length = file.length();
if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
     // File is too large
}
byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)length];
int offset = 0;
int numRead = 0;
while (offset < bytes.length && (numRead=is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length-offset))    >= 0) {
   offset += numRead;
}
if (offset < bytes.length) {
   throw new IOException("Could not completely read file "+file.getName());
}
is.close();
String Attachment=Base64.encodeBase64String(bytes);
vars.put("SoapAttachment",Attachment);
```

Use SoapAttachment in your XML with ${SoapAttachment}.

Note - you might have to remove few imports as i am doing checksum calculation so i need them.